# PHP - Search for value inside a multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, oop, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional `$array`. One of its column is `customer name`.
I have to save all the rows of `array` in a db, except for the rows with the same `customer name`.

I've written a function called `searchMultidimensionalArray` which creates an array that contains all the rows with different `customer name`. Before inserting a row in the db, I search for the current row in that array. If present, I do nothing, else I store the current row.

Here's my solution, but It's not working properly.

```
public function searchMultidimensionalArray($valueName, $arrayCustomer)
{
    foreach ($arrayCustomer as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['name'] === $valueName) {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

This is where I loop through the array:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < $countArray; $i++) {
    $customer = new Customer();
    $customer->setName($customerName); // I already have $customerName data
    if ($i == 1) {

        $arrayCustomer[$i] = [
            'name' => $customerName,
        ];

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($customer);
        $em->flush();

    }
    if ($this->searchMultidimensionalArray($customerName, $arrayCustomer) == true) {

        $repository = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Customer');
        $customer = $repository->findOneBy(['name' => $customerName]);
    } else {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($customer);
        $em->flush();

        $arrayCustomer[$i] = [
            'name' => $customerName,
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: @Condorcho The rows with the same ' customer name ' are all stored in the db

Answer (score 0):

Unless I am misunderstanding your case, the desired result can be efficiently achieved a couple of ways.

1. **The DB way**:  Set up your database table so that the `name` column is a unique key.  That way if you try to `INSERT` a duplicate, the row will fail as desired.
2. **The PHP way**:  I would recommend [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) like this:

   ```
   $unique_customer_names=array_unique(array_column($arrayCustomer,'customer_name'));
   ```

   Then use `$unique_customer_names` to identify duplicates.

I hope one of these options provides a preferable solution for you.